# PUT request to API returns 403(forbidden)

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403

I am building a network for a project due in few months and i am am currently working on the liking system. I have put a glyph inside a button tag as the button and supposedly when you click, it makes a PUT request to the server and it changes likes to likes + 1. But when I did so it returned a 403(Forbidden).

Past cases of this status code usually are solved by adding a csrf token to the form, but i did that in django where they have it automatically. I have never experienced this in Java script.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector("#like").addEventListener('click', () => {
        var num = document.querySelector("#like").value;
        addlike(num)
    })
})

    const addlike = id => {
        console.log("Ran")
        fetch(`/posts/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(post => {
            var newamount = post.likes + 1;
            fetch(`/posts/${id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    likes: 2
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

In the file above, I waited for content to load, and everytime a user clicked, it would increment likes by 1. I have done a console.log() to see if the json object i fetched the first time was correct and there was nothing wrong. How would i avoid the 403 Code?

Comment: well your javascript probably has no impact on the server side forbidden response

Comment: well that's because the server just **forbids** you. So check with the server/API to see if there is any authorization/authentication required - maybe a token a Bearer authorization header. Or it could just be a bug in the server code. Again, recheck the server.

Comment: I see no authorization in your request, so that may be the cause of forbidden error

Comment: but i serialized a model from the views myself and i dont remember setting down any authorization